# UIActivityViewController open list of navigation apps

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want to open list of navigation apps, like if you want to post you get facebook,twitter etc, like that i want to open navigation apps install in phone like google maps, ios map

i am searching for hours for same but didn't find anything.

my question is is it possible ? if yes then please suggest me way to do this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't ask iOS to provide a list of apps for a specific purpose. But you can create your own custom Activities for a specific app and only show them if they are installed.

For example the `JBWhatsAppActivity` (https://github.com/jberlana/JBWhatsAppActivity).

You can also share your custom content.

Comment: i want map related apps not message

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using UIActivityViewController. simple demo here. Hope this will help you. And if you want map related apps only then you can add in

activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[ UIActivityTypesGmap or the apps you want you can add here ]

```
- (IBAction)shareBtnTapped:(id)sender {

   // anything you want to post, suppose here we share text  

  NSString *sharetext = @"hi i am sharing text";
  NSArray *activityItems = @[sharetext]


  UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

  activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePostToFacebook,UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeMessage];

[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```